# Acceder a un control que está dentro de un UserControl des de un Formulario

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms

He creado un proyecto del tipo Librería de clases, y he añadido un UserControl y un Formulario.
El UserControl tiene un control del tipo ListBox.

El problema es que me gustaría des del formulario acceder al control Listbox que hay dentro del UserControl pero no tengo claro como hacerlo, me gustaría hacerlo de una manera simple, he probado con este código pero no funciona:
`((DynamicList)UserControl).ListBoxItems.Items.Add(TextBoxItemText.Text);`

Me sale este error: 'UserControl' es tipo, que no es válida en el contexto indicado

Muchas gracias.

Comment: cuando instancias el userControl. Debes llamar ejemplo userControl1..ListBoxItems.Items.Add(TextBoxItemText.Text); no necesitas hacer un cast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes crear una propiedad pública que exponga el Listbox fuera de los límites del user control.

Este ejemplo requiere que el nombre del `Usercontrol` sea `MiUserControl` y que tenga un `ListBox` llamado `listBox1`.

```
public partial class MiUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MiUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Aquí comienza la declaración de la propiedad pública

    // Estos dos atributos permiten que la propiedad sea mostrada 
    // en la ventana de propiedades del diseñador.
    [Description("El ListBox que está dentro del UserControl.")]
    [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    
    // Esta es la propiedad en sí
    public ListBox ListBoxItems
    {
        get
        {
            return listBox1;
        }
    }
    // Hasta aquí la declaración de la propiedad
}
```

Vale destacar que la propiedad creada es de solo lectura (no tiene setter) para evitar que el `ListBox` pueda ser reemplazado desde afuera con un código similar a este `miUserControl1.ListBoxItems = new ListBox();`. Esto no afecta la capacidad de agregar / eliminar items.

Así se ve en la ventana de propiedades

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]